# Why my cron job runs every 10 seconds?

Tags: liferay-6

Environment: Liferay 6.1

In my liferay-portlet.xml I have this cron job:

```
<scheduler-entry>
         <scheduler-event-listener-class>com.shorex.b2b.web.billing.IndexJob</scheduler-event-listener-class>
         <trigger>
            <cron>
                <cron-trigger-value>0 0 6 1/1 * ? *</cron-trigger-value>
            </cron> 
        </trigger>
    </scheduler-entry>
```

This expresion "0 0 6 1/1 * ? *" means that there is a process which will be execute once every day at 6:00:00.

The problem is that this process is been executed since 6:00:00 every 10 seconds. that is, at 6:00:00, 6:00:10, 6:00:20, 6:00:30...

Could anyone tell me why is it happening?

Comment: 1/1? Why not `0 0 6 * * ?` Fire at 6pm (noon) every day

Comment: I got this expresion from http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: I found it here http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/1.8.5/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<cron-trigger-value>0 0 6 ? * *</cron-trigger-value>
```

thats every day at 6.

Comment: as to why it was happening:

    0 0 6 
was fine 0 seconds, 0 minutes, 6 hours

   1/1
was an odd way of saying everyday (on the day). I think this is being interpreted as 'run on the day where the day is NOW' and so the script executes every times its run and only gets evaluated every 10 seconds... 

    * 
every month

    ? *

on the specific day that is 'everyday'

Comment: Just a thought, but you should really update your answer with the information in your comment, rather than just add it as a comment. :-)